# overflow:hidden on div tag affects background color

Tags: html, css

The definition of `overflow:hidden` states that :

`the overflowing content is completely hidden, not accessible to the user.`

from: http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/overflow.html

But i am curious about this behavior from my js fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/gd62qmr3/2/

One thing i noticed is that, it gave color to the margins after setting the overflow to hidden?

```
<div style="background-color:green;overflow:hidden;">
<p>test</p>
</div>
```

I wanna know why did such behavior occur? the exact block element will have the green background color if there is no overflow but putting overflow will give background color to its margins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `overflow: hidden` affects margin collapse.

`p` elements have some vertical margin by default. According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins), it collapses with the margin of the parent `div`:

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or
>   might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins
>   that combine this way are said to *collapse*, and the resulting combined
>   margin is called a *collapsed margin*.
>
> Adjoining vertical margins collapse<sub><sup>, except [... not
>   relevant]</sup></sub>
>
> [... The] top margin of a box and top margin of its first in-flow
>   child [are adjoining]

[image]

However, `overflow: hidden` prevents that:

> Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts (such
>   as floats and elements with [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#propdef-overflow) other than `visible`) do not
>   collapse with their in-flow children.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your color is set to the parent of your paragraph.  You have nothing stopping the height of your parent div to expand as far as it wants, so the paragraph margins are making the parent height larger.

If you were to give a set height to your parent (18px or so) then it will hide the margins (and text technically)

```
div {
    height:18px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gd62qmr3/3/

If you were to set the color to your paragraph, then you will not see the background color in the margins

```
div {
    overflow:hidden;
}
div p {
    background-color:green;
    margin:20px 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gd62qmr3/4/